# Spring 4 - web form-bean fields not populated

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, wildfly-8, spring-4

In my spring based web-application, deploying it in the JBoss Wildfly 8.1, the form `Validator` class receives the form-bean with all the page fields empty/null. My validator

```
@Component
public class CampaignValidator implements Validator {


    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
       Campaign campaign = (Campaign) target;
        //campaign fields are empty/null
    }
}
```

The same code is running without any errors in the tc server and Wildfly 9.0 Alpha. I couldn't figure out what is wrong in my configurations? My application security,

```
@Override
protected void _configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll()
                // .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(successHandler).and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll();
    }
```

My controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("quickCampaignbean")
public class QuickCampaignController {

    Validator @Autowired @Qualifier("quickCampaignValidator") validator;

    @InitBinder
    public void bind(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/quickcampaign", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadCreatePage(@AuthenticationPrincipal LoginUser user,
            ModelMap model) {
        // load initial page values
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/quickcampaign", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createQuickCampaignGroup(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("quickCampaignbean") QuickCampaign quickCampaignbean,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model,
            @AuthenticationPrincipal LoginUser user) throws Throwable {
         // fetch the form values from the bean, populate service bean and
         // call service, perhaps only if no errors
    }
}
```

I could not find why the same app works in the Wildfly 9.0, Fabris tc Server without any problem, but with errors in Wildfly 8.1?